# How do I prove that every bounded infinite subset of R has at least one cluster point

Tags: real-analysis

I tried proving this with the nested interval theorem and failed. I think that I should use the Bolzano-Weistrass Theorem to prove, but I can't figure out how to complete this.

Comment: This URL has one such proof http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sparling/23014/23014notes6/node23.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider splitting your subset into two pieces. Either an infinite amount of points lie on one side of the split, or an infinite amount of points lie on the other. Then, split the one that has an infinite amount in half (if both have an infinite amount, pick one side) and repeat. Do you see how this assures that there is a cluster point?

Comment: This was the mindset I had when I first tried to prove this. I then used the nested interval theorem to show that it converged to a single point, say a, that was the cluster point. My professor told me that the end of my proof was incorrect. He said that I needed to finish the proof showing that for all r>0 the subset of the reals intersected with (a-r,a+r)\{a} was not empty. Can you help explain how I would do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $M$ be any bound on your set. Bisect the interval $[-M, M]$ into $$[-M, 0] \cup [0, M]$$

One of these contains infinitely many points of your set; let's say it's $[0, M]$. Choose a point from your set lying in $[0, M]$ and call it $x_1$.

Now bisect $[0, M]$ into two pieces and come up with a way to define $x_2$ in an analogous manner. Then bisect again. Do you see how to define a sequence, and then prove it's convergent?

---

Morally, this is exactly the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you explain the end of the proof some more? I am having a hard time understanding. Is proving that it is convergent enough to prove that there is a cluster point? I was told by my professor that I needed to finish the proof showing that for all r>0 the subset of the reals intersected with (a-r,a+r)\{a} was not empty. Can you help explain how I would do this?

Comment: @Shelly The length of each interval is something like $M/2^{n - 1}$. So given $r$ choose $n$ large enough that $M/2^{n - 1} < r$ and see what happens.